# how git manage modified files efficiently

Tags: git

I'm reading a Git book and below is a picture from the book:
[image]

We know that Git doesn’t store data as a series of changesets or
differences, but instead as a series of snapshots, which means that for any modified files, git will store a brand new file as blob internally.

For example, let's say the picture show three commits and 3 blobs(corresponds to three files).
Let's say I modified a file(blob cba0a) and committed on the second commit(34ac2), since I modified the file, the tree list will point to a new file(blob), let's say the file on the first commit contains  thousands lines of text, and I just appended one new line to the file on the second commit, so the new blob will have so much duplicated content stored on the disk, which is very inefficient, isn't it

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but this is git's design. What alternative would solve this "problem", according to you? Storing "only changes" would be a totally different design, with its own caveats.

Comment: As to your follow-up question: there are multiple reasons why `TREE` objects are more efficient than storing all the paths directly in the `COMMIT`.  One is that it speeds up diff detection.  (If two versions have the same `TREE` hash, there's no need to iterate over files - you already know the whole tree matches.)  Also it reduces duplication of data between commits (because `TREE` objects can be shared).

Answer (score 2):

> We know that Git doesn’t store data as a series of changesets or differences, but instead as a series of snapshots, which means that for any modified files, git will store a brand new file as blob internally.

That is not entirely accurate.

When a new object (such as a blob for a file) is initially created, it is stored as a "loose" object, in a way that optimizes for quick access.  So *initially* the internal format is pretty much what you describe - the `BLOB` is a distinct file on disk, stored with a directory/filename derived from the object ID, containing exactly that version of the source file.

These loose files are still compressed, which is one of the reasons git is "better" at storing text files (like source code) than binary files.

But there is a second representation of objects in git - packed objects.  This representation sacrifices *some* speed of access in order to make the storage on disk more efficient - both by storing one file in place of many and by reducing similar objects (such as versions of a file) to chains of patches.  (These chains still optimize for looking at the latest version; the latest version is a true snapshot, the second latest as a diff from the latest - assuming it's similar enough - etc.)

This can seem confusing because git documentation does always talk about snapshots.  Conceptually that is what is stored, always.  But physically those snapshots are sometimes implemented in a way that takes advantage of diffs[1].

There are various times when files are moved from loose form to packed form. Files are always packed for transmission to (or from) a remote.

The trade-offs around storage efficiency have gotten *a lot* of thought in git; you *can* worry about trying to force git to repack at times if you want, but there's not really any reason to do anything at all about it; git is avoiding duplication when it makes sense to do it.

> [...] which is very inefficient, isn't it

Not really.  It's a trade-off (against speed of access) that git is actively managing.

---

[1] The first way git 'makes snapshots from diffs' you may already know about:  a new snapshot of a directory (a `TREE`) can reference some or all of the same `BLOB`s as the previous `TREE`.  So it's a new snapshot, but it reuses parts of the old one.

What I mention above about packed representation is another way.  When two objects are "similar enough', the older one is converted.  The pack index entry for that object is updated to say "object abc is derived from object xyz", and the actual pack data for abc is just a patch.  The pack also indicates how many levels of derivation are needed to fully reconstitute the object's snapshot (i.e. "abc is derived from xyz" is visibly different from "abc is derived from xyz which is itself derived from another object).

Answer (score -1):

Your analysis is correct.

But don't worry: Git knows how to store data efficiently and without much redundancy. In the vast majority of cases it is irrelevant how that works. For the mental model that is needed to work with Git effectively, it is sufficient to know that "Git stores snapshots".

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am just a beginner in Git, just want to know whether my analysis is correct or not,  not really worry about how git gets the job done

Comment: No, the analysis is not correct.  The analysis in the question explicitly states that git will store each version independently, which is factually incorrect.  The "snapshots" model MIGHT be sufficient for most users'  understanding, but it is directly misleading in the context of the specific question asked and the difference absolutely has consequences for users